# How do I know which app version is being replaced with android?

Tags: android, version-control, replace, broadcastreceiver, upgrade

I have an update that I want to run for my app based on what the previous version of the app is.

For example, if the user has version 1-5 and they are upgrading to 6 or 7 I want to run the update.  Also, I don't want to run the update if they are upgrading from 6 to 7.

I've tried to accomplish this using a broadcast receiver that accepts the PACKAGE_REMOVE and PACKAGE_REPLACE intents but they don't seem to give me the information about the app that is being removed.  I don't get the PACKAGE_REMOVED intent unless I'm reinstalling the same version.  It's hard to tell because the debugger and the log print don't seem to catch before the intents are received.  Any ideas?

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (isOccurUpdated) {
        return;
    }
    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED")) {
        String name = info.versionName;
        // We are assuming that we didn't get down here if we have already
        // done this update
        Log.d(TAG,"We receive the REPLACE intent "+name);
        if (name.contains(OCCUR_ID_UPDATE) || name.contains(OCCUR_ID_UPDATE_FIX)) {
            dbh.occurIdUpdate();
        }
    } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED")) {
        String name = info.versionName;
        if (name.contains(OCCUR_ID_UPDATE)) {
            isOccurUpdated = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to store previous-version information yourself somewhere, such as:

Step #1: Create a custom `Application` class, and define it in your manifest (`android:name` attribute of `<application>`).

Step #2: In `onCreate()` of your custom `Application` class, read in some persistent data structure that contains the version number of your app the last time `onCreate()` ran. For example, you could have a `lastVersion` value in your `SharedPreferences`.

Step #3: If you see that the last version is older than your current version, do whatever upgrade logic you want.

Step #4: Write your current version out to that persistent data structure (e.g., update the `SharedPreferences`).

If this is more tied to database logic, `SQLiteOpenHelper` handles all of this for you.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this solution doesn't solve the problem when the custom Application class hasn't run before the new install.  Using the example from above, if I have version 7 checking for the lastVersion on the initial install then it will always receive null, right?

Comment: @user1196031: If the user installs version 6, then upgrades to 7 without having run anything, the user is at the same point they would be if they installed 7 directly. Hence, there is no upgrade logic that you could possibly need to run.

Comment: Version 6 runs the update automatically but 7 needs to check if 6 was already installed before running the update.  The update will ruin everything if it runs twice.  I realize now that I should have done this by doing a database upgrade though since there isn't a way to check if the upgrade has ran or not.  I'm guessing there isn't a way to find out what version of the software we are replacing?

Comment: @user1196031: "I'm guessing there isn't a way to find out what version of the software we are replacing?" -- not unless you saved that information yourself somewhere, which is the point behind my answer.

Comment: If you care to update your answer to include "not unless you saved that information yourself somewhere, which is the point behind my answer" I can except your answer.